# Safest highest operating temperature of a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: hardware, temperature, cpu

What is the safest highest operating temperature of a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

I was able to get my temperature up to **77'C** by running:

```
fulload() { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null & }; fulload; read; killall --signal SIGKILL dd
```

My temperature readings came via:

```
watch --interval 1 /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

Comment: IIRC you get a warning at 70 or 75 degrees celsius and the CPU is throttled at 77 or 80 So I would say the max safe temp is 75. Having said that no real world workload is likely to hammer the CPU the same way your test did. BTW you can double check my figures by using the GUI and watching the thermometer (in the newest version of Jessie) or the temp widget (you may need to add this manually) or colored quare (in the up.per right corner of the screen)